# A homeomorphism in plane and number of components

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Suppose that we know the Jordan curve theorem. How to prove the following theorem:

> Let $K$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ and the set $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus K$ has $k\in \mathbb{N}$ components. If $h:K\rightarrow h(K)\subset \mathbb{R^2}$ is a homeomorphism, then the set $\mathbb{R^2} \setminus h(K)$ has $k\in \mathbb{N}$ components.

Comment: I doubt that the Jordan curve theorem will help, $K$ can be very weird. You need some ingredients from algebraic topology.

Comment: What one might say is that if you know *how to prove* the Jordan curve theorem by a specific technique --- namely, Alexander duality --- then you can follow the same technique to prove this statement. Historically, Alexander Duality was developed as a generalization of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Can you provide more context for this problem? Is this something that you know is true and you have a citation for, or is it something you're conjecturing? Do you really want $K$ to be an arbitrary compact subset, or do you want it to be a union of curves so that you can try to apply the Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: @William For example, see on google books *Nonlinear functional analysis* - **Deimling,** page 26.

Answer (score -1):

I can see that geometrically. $K$ is homotopic  to a finite number of circles glued to each other (i.e. each circle is a Jordan curve). Now we can embed this "curve" inside the unit ball $\mathbb B^3$ in $\mathbb R^3$ as follows $K\ni (x,y)\mapsto (x,y,0)\in \mathbb B^3$..

Now you can count the fundamental group $W:= \mathbb B^3\setminus K$ as follows: $W$ is homotopic (contarctable) to a  space consisting of a sphere $S^2$ and finitely many (vertical infinite) cylinders live inside it.. Hence $\pi_1(W)= \bigstar_n \mathbb Z$ where $\star$ denotes the free product and $n$ is the number of components.. Clearly, any homeomorphism $h$ doesn't change $n$.

Comment: Why is $K$ homotopy equivalent to a finite wedge of circles?  Arbitrary compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be weird, and contain things like Cantor sets.

Comment: @William of course! but since the question starts with "

Suppose that we know the Jordan curve theorem" then I assumed that the region is enclosed by an image of the real line with finitely many self intersections .. Don't you think he meant this? Otherwise how would one count the connected components of  the complementary of a cantor set?

Comment: If you consider the Cantor set $C \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, the complement in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a single connected component, so counting the components of the complement is certainly possible. (Even if the complement has uncountably many components, it's still a cardinal number.) The difficult part of this problem is ensuring that nothing exotic or unexpected happens, so just saying "I can see that geometrically..." is maybe not a sufficient argument.

Comment: I think that if they wanted to assume that $K$ was a union of curves, they would have made that assumption instead of only stating that $K$ is a compact set

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for answering. Apparently any direct method needs to apply some topological classification property.

Comment: $K$ is not even assumed to be connected.